Разворот байт в HEX
Подскажите, пожалуйста, как в Delphi развернуть HEX число
Имеем число в Hex например: 2300FFC0
Нужно его развернуть: C0FF0023

Если сдвиги и операция | (побитовое or) там есть, то очевидно. Иначе брать остатки от деления, а потом формировать результат умножением и суммированием (сдвиг вправо на 8 это деление на 256, сдвиг влево на 8 это умножение на 256) –
avp
Commented 10 минут назад

Самый простой способ, это перегнать в стринг, потом в стринге Str[N] брать как символы в другой стринг. И стринг в HEX конверт. Да это не самый быстрый способ, но простой и понятный ;)

Да я первым делом подумал о таком варианте с преобразованием в текстовую строку, но решил, что есть же правильные решения этой задачи

Несколько из возможных способов:
procedure TForm2.Button20Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  a, b, c, d, e: DWord;

function ReverseD0(i: DWord): DWord;  //32 и 64 bit
asm
   {$IFDEF CPUX64}
   mov eax, i
   {$ENDIF}
   bswap eax
end;

function ReverseD1(i: DWord): DWord;
begin
  Result := ((i and $FF) shl 24) or
            (((i shr 8) and $FF) shl 16) or
            (((i shr 16) and $FF) shl 8) or
            (((i shr 24) and $FF));
end;

function ReverseD2(i: DWord): DWord;
begin
  Longrec(Result).Bytes[0] := Longrec(i).Bytes[3];
  Longrec(Result).Bytes[1] := Longrec(i).Bytes[2];
  Longrec(Result).Bytes[2] := Longrec(i).Bytes[1];
  Longrec(Result).Bytes[3] := Longrec(i).Bytes[0];
end;

function ReverseD3(i: DWord): DWord;
var
  c: Integer;
begin
  for c := 0 to 3 do
     PByteArray(@Result)[c] := PByteArray(@i)[3-c];
end;

begin
  a := $AABBCCDD;
  b := ReverseD0(a);
  c := ReverseD1(a);
  d := ReverseD2(a);
  e := ReverseD3(a);
  Memo1.Lines.Add(Format('%x %x %x %x %x', [a, b, c, d, e]));
end;

>>>  AABBCCDD DDCCBBAA DDCCBBAA DDCCBBAA DDCCBBAA

"hex" - это способ представления чисел для человека, и я полагаю, что у вас просто число, а не строка.

Супер ответ. Несколько на выбор в том числе и на Ассемблере!! Отлично!!

Похоже для функции ReverseD2 нужно дописать в конце: Result:= longWord(d) иначе на выходе 0

@Александр Поменял, лучше вообще без промежуточных переменных (хотел компактнее сделать).

спасибо большое за уточнение

В ReverseD0 можно добавить {$IFDEF CPUX64} mov   eax, ecx {$ENDIF} и остальные больше не нужны в принципе...

@MBo, можно же var c: LongRec absolute i; и по аналогии с Result.

@Alekcvp Регистр для аргумента (rсx, rdx)  отличается в зависимости от того - глобальная функция или вложенная, поэтому лучше явное i применить. Про absolute решил не писать, вариантные записи по сути то же делают.

@Alekcvp, а, что именно дает ( {$IFDEF CPUX64} mov   eax, ecx {$ENDIF})?

Этот кусок кода исполняется в 64-битном режиме, при котором первый аргумент функции передается не в регистре eax, как в 32 битах, а в регистре rcx, но у меня в коде это вложенная функция со скрытым аргументом, поэтому в регистре rdx, а для универсальности я отдал это на откуп компилятору , указав имя аргумента

@MBo, вот наглядно для чего нужны отступы во вложенных функциях. Первая procedure при беглом взгляде воспринимается как program...

program Reverse;

var
  hexValue, x, r: Int64;
//***********************************************************************  
 //Не знаю как с этим компилятором вывести hex 
 //для вывода эта функция
function IntToHex(Value: Int64): string;
var pos:integer;
    HexChars:string;
    Result:string;
begin 
Result:='';
while Value>0 do
  begin
   HexChars := '0123456789ABCDEF';
   pos:=Value mod $10;
   Result := HexChars[pos + 1] + Result;
   Value:=Value div $10;
  end;
  IntToHex:= Result;
end;
//************************************************************************
// программа  реверс
begin
  hexValue := $2300FFC0;// Оставим исходное число для вывода, по желанию
  x:= hexValue;
  r := 0;
  while x > 0 do 
  begin
    r := r * $100 + (x mod $100); // остаток от деления прибавляем к перевертышу 
    x := x div $100; 
  end;
  writeln('hexValue  ',IntToHex(hexValue));
  writeln('Reverse   ',IntToHex(r));


end.


Output:

hexValue  2300FFC0
Reverse   C0FF0023

https://onecompiler.com/pascal/42xjbtcsm

Хороший вариант

Кажется я теперь понимаю, почему современные программы такие тормознутые...

Функция IntToHex есть в SysUtils, не надо велосипедить на ровном месте. https://onecompiler.com/pascal/42xq2gbyj

Кроме того, функция работает неверно. Введите число 0000FFC0, ответ должен быть C0FF0000, а у вас получается 0000C0FF

@zed если работать со строками 0000FFC0 ->C0FF0000, если числа то FFC0 ->C0FF все верно.

При чём тут строки? Если я правильно понимаю вопрос, то задача перевести 32-х битное число из BigEndian в LittleEndian. И у вашего кода с этим беда. Сравните свои результаты, с кодом из ответа @MBo (для значений с лидирующими нулями).
